# Django migrations for a cloned db

Tags: django

I cloned a `postgres` db and added a new model to one of the apps. Our project contains many apps.

Now When I ran `migrations`, `migrate` it would fail. So I commented that model out, deleted migrations.py file from folder and ran fake migrations. Than again put that model in and ran `migrations`, `migrate`. Things were fine.

But now I deleted this model table from db manually and when would run migrations it would show model doesn't exist.

Basically I would need to again and again tweak the model, delete, update table. 
So I searched for migrating from scratch. Did delete some apps from `django_migrations` table. But it is not working out it shows relations already existing.

This is all becoming confusing, `--fake`, `delete`, `squash` what to do?

Basically if I drop table django_migrations, delete migrations folder from app. Can't django automatically sync with db and understand what model exist and what don't and figure it out itself.

Comment: Redo the clone. Without doing anything else, run migrate. What is the error you run into? This is vital to know. Just trying to work around it, gets you into more trouble, as you found out.

Comment: Anyway without like cloning again, this would mean again and again cloning. Also it requires admin permission, mail chain, etc.

Comment: No it doesn't. The key issue is to find out if your code base is consistent with your clone. Note that I said "run migrate", not "run makemigrations then run migrate". Only migrate. That makes sure your codebase and clone are in sync. Also not entirely sure what your end goal is? Why would you manually delete a table from the database?

Comment: I had a clone made again, and only ran `python manage.py migrate`, also had deleted the migration file from folder. But ressulted in error - `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists`

Comment: Had many migrations file so had to delete than from individual apps, after that running migrate shows, `No migrations to apply`

Comment: Right, so your clone doesn't contain the **data** from `django_migrations` table and there's your error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a clone of a Django database, without the data, there's one table you should always get the data from: `django_migrations`. This is the table that holds the state of the database: which migrations have been applied and as such what models exist already.

The fact that Django tries to create one it's core models tells me you didn't have the data from `django_migrations` in the clone.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem.

- deleted all the data from 'django_migrations' table.
- deleted all the migrations file from all migrations folder in different apps
- Commented out the models whose table are still not in database
- ran `python manage.py makemigrations`
- ran `python manage.py migrate --fake`
- Put the comments off the model
- ran `python manage.py makemigrations`
- ran `python manage.py migrate`

Thing is to understand what does `makemigrations` and `migrate` does. And then you can delete/update manually or created new models and migrate/clone things etc. it would work. For a new starter these commands are little confusing.

Let's says everything is empty i.e. no files in migration folder of app.
Than `makemigrations` makes these files which contains say sqls/syntax on how to create your table. With each change it will create a new one, with only the changes listed in that.

`migrate` creates actual empty tables in the database. And creates an entry in `django_migrations` against the app that model was part of. This entry tells it when was the latest entries from that file were applied to the database.

**Scenario 1:**
I deleted one table manually from db. Now django doesn't know about it. So if you would run `makemigrations` or `migrate` it would do nothing.

**Scenario 2:**
I deleted all entries from `django_migrations`, deleted `migrations` files from app. Tables are still in db. Now when I do `makemigrations` it works, but when I migrate it throws error that already existing.

**Scenario 3:**
Have deleted entries from `django_migrations` and `migration` files. Django has one option of `migrate --fake`, this tells it that tables are already existing just make entries in `django_migrations` table. so `makemigrations` and `migrate --fake` works now without error. But now the table which I deleted manually is still deleted, django hadn't made it. So will throw error when I try to access it.

**Scenario 4:**
The one I described at start. I faked the entries which were in db and then migrated the model which wasn't in db.

So once one understands what's it's doing behind the scenes many approaches could have been followed, create the table schema manually or selectively pick `django_migrations` or `migrations` file entries and delete them. But best is to delete everything and start from scratch.

It would have been best that django understands that these are tables already created, these are models I have, create the missing one, leave the existing ones. If any discrepancy show them. I see so many questions related to migrations and people are confused here and there.